# SelectMany while Referencing Parent

Tags: linq

Given

```
List<Foo> foos;

public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public double Score { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to output, for each object in `foos`, the property Foo.Name along with the maximum Bar.Score.  I see how to get the maximum score:

```
foos.SelectMany(f => f.Bars).MaxBy(b => b.Score).Select(b => b.Score);
```

Is there a way to get the corresponding Name as well, without adding a reference from Bar back to Foo?  If I made the following change

```
public class Bar
{
    public Foo Foo { get; set; } // Can't really add this
    public double Score { get; set; }
}
```

I could do

```
foos.SelectMany(f => f.Bars).MaxBy(b => b.Score)
    .Select(b => new { Name = b.Foo.Name, Score = b.Score) });
```

However in the real case, I cannot add the back reference.

Comment: Why not just `foos.Select(f => new { Name = f.Name, MaxScore = f.Bars.Max(b => b.Score) })`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `SelectMany`, just use `Select` with `Max`:

```
var result = foos
    .Select(f => new 
    { 
        Name = f.Name, 
        MaxScore = f.Bars.Max(b => b.Score) 
    });
```